# Quotient of Gaussian Integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, gaussian-integers

Consider the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}[i]/I$ where $I$ is the ideal $\{m+in : m,n \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ with same parity}\}$. To which commutative ring is it isomorphic?

I thought of finding an appropriate ring homomorphism for which $I$ is the kernel, but somehow I did not succeed. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the (surjective) map

$$\begin{cases}\Bbb Z[i]\to\Bbb Z/2 \\ m+ni\mapsto m+n\mod 2\end{cases}$$

which clearly has as kernel the ideal $I$. By the first isomorphism $\Bbb Z[i]/I\cong\Bbb Z/2$.

Comment: Does the downvoter care to comment what he thinks is incorrect?

Comment: Sorry to ask you again, but how would I prove the property $\varphi(rs) = \varphi(r)\varphi(s)$?

Comment: @TheGeekGreek you can just write out the definitions and verifty $(a+bi)(c+di) = (ac-bd)+i(ad+bc)$ so you get $a(c+d)+b(c-d)$ on the LHS and $(a+b)(c+d) = a(c+d)+b(c+d)$ on the RHS. But since $1=-1\mod 2$, you get that the images match.

Comment: The part with $1 = -1 \mod 2$ was crucial and I was not entirely sure. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly different way to do it.

**Claim**: $I = (1+i)$.  The containment $\supseteq$ is clear.  Note that $2 = (1-i)(1+i) \in (1+i)$.  Given $m+in \in I$, if $m,n$ are both even, then $m+in \in (2) \subseteq (1+i)$.  If $m,n$ are both odd, then $m-1,n-1$ are both even, so $m+in - (1+i) = (m - 1) + i (n - 1) \in (2) \subseteq (1+i)$.  Thus $m+in \in (1+i)$.

By the Third Isomorphism Theorem, then
\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathbb{Z}[i]}{I} = \frac{\mathbb{Z}[i]}{(1+i)} \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{(1+x, x^2+1)} \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{((-1)^2 + 1)} = \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{(2)} \, .
\end{align*}

Comment: Oh, very nice approach! +1