# Ideal of Gaussian Integers Ring. Congruence Classes

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modular-arithmetic, ideals

**Let $I = \{a+bi \in \mathbb{Z}[i] \; / \; [a]_2 = [b]_2\}$ be an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ where $[a]_2 = \{a+2n \;/\; n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$**

**(a) Prove that I is generated by $1 + i$**

I solved it this way:

|$\subseteq$
$$[1]_2=[1]_2\Rightarrow 1+i \in I$$

|$\supseteq$
$$ z \in I \Rightarrow z = x+yi \; / \; [x]_2=[y]_2 \Rightarrow y-x=2n\;/\;x,y,n \in \mathbb{Z}\Rightarrow y=x+2n\; \land \; x=y-2n \;/\;x,y,n \in \mathbb{Z} \Rightarrow z \in (1+i) $$

But I’m not sure if it is correct.

**(b) How many elements does $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(1+i) $have?**

I think $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(1+i)=\{[1+i]\}$ but I don’t know how to prove it.

*I really appreciate your help.*

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  In $\mathbb Z[i]/(1+i),  [1+i]=[0]$

Comment: Thanks @J.W.Tanner! I have already notice that $[1+i]=[0]$ so I edited the post. Any idea if **(a)** is correct?

Comment: Regarding (b), what about $[1]$?

Comment: Your (a) is hard to follow.  Could you show if $x+yi\in I$ then $\dfrac{x+yi}{1+i}\in\mathbb Z[i]$?

Comment: I don’t see why $[1]\in\mathbb{Z}[i]/I$ because $[a]_2=[b]_2 \not\Rightarrow [1-a]_2= [b]_2 $ I’m surely wrong @J.W.Tanner

Comment: $[1]\not \in  I$ but $[1]\in \mathbb Z[I]/I$; I think $\mathbb Z[i]/I\cong \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner In (a) you mean proceeding this way? $$ \frac{x+yi}{1+i}=\frac{(x-y)+(x+y)i}{2}=\frac{2n+2ki}{2}=n+ki\;/\;n,k \in \mathbb{Z} $$

Comment: Yes, that shows if $x+yi\in I$ then $x+yi=(1+i)g$ for some $g\in\mathbb Z[i]$

Comment: For part (b) see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2309649/the-quotient-ring-mathbbzi-1-i).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Quotient of Gaussian Integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2055502/quotient-of-gaussian-integers)

Comment: @André3000 Not at all because so far I only know a few definitions about modular arithmetic and rings. Anyway thanks for your help an I think the key is understand that a and b has the same parity as [Quotient of Gaussian Integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2055502/quotient-of-gaussian-integers) says. I already understood the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(a)** It is definitely correct that $I=(1+i)$, although I have some comments that I hope will be helpful.

First, in your proof that $(1+i)\subseteq I$, you've only proved that $1+i\in I$. Note that this is enough to show that $(1+i)\subseteq I$ if you know that $I$ is an ideal. I think you should show that $I$ is an ideal of $\Bbb{Z}[1+i]$.

Second, I'm not sure that I understand your proof that $I\subseteq(1+i)$. Below, I've written a few steps that you can add to make it more clear. Note: the main observation is that $2=(1+i)(1-i)$.

$$\text{Let }z\in I$$
$$z=x+iy\text{ for some }x,y\in\Bbb{Z}\text{ with }x\equiv y\text{ mod }2$$
$$y=x+2n\text{ for some }n\in\Bbb{Z}$$
$$z=x+iy=x+i(x+2n)=x(1+i)+2in=(1+i)\cdot\left[x+i(1-i)n\right]$$
$$z\in(1+i)$$

**(b)** $\left\vert\Bbb{Z}[i]/(1+i)\right\vert=2$.

Note that for every $x,y\in\Bbb{Z}$ there are two possibilities: either $x\equiv y$ modulo $2$, or $x\not\equiv y$ modulo $2$. You've already shown that

$$(1+i)=\{x+iy\,\vert\,x\equiv y\text{ mod }2\}.$$

It is enough to show that

$$1+(1+i)=\{x+iy\,\vert\,x\not\equiv y\text{ mod }2\}.$$

Comment: Will the person who downvoted my answer please provide feedback?

Comment: It looks like someone downvoted both answers here, as well as both the linked questions and several of the answers there.

Answer (score 1):

$I$ is precisely the kernel of the ring epimorphism $\psi:a+bi\mapsto [a]_2+[b]_2$ from $\Bbb Z[i]$ to $\Bbb F_2$ where $[x]_2$ denotes the residue class $x+2\Bbb Z$. Therefore $\frac{\Bbb Z[i]}{I}\approx\Bbb F_2$ and $|\frac{\Bbb Z[i]}{I}\vert=2$. $$\forall z_1,z_2\in\Bbb Z[i]\;\;1+i=z_1z_2\implies 2=|z_1|^2|z_2|^2\implies z_1=1\lor z_2=1$$
Therefore $\langle 1+i\rangle$ is maximal because $1+i$ is irreducible and thus prime as $\Bbb Z[i]$ is a principal ideal domain. Therefore we must have $I=\langle 1+i\rangle$ because $\langle 1+i\rangle\subseteq I$; i.e. $1\equiv 1\;\text{mod}\;2$ and so $1+i\in I$.

Comment: I appreciate it! But I don’t understand why R/I ={[0], [1]} My knowledge about this is so basic as I have had just one lecture about this topic. Could you explain it in a more basic way, please?

Comment: @user152985. I'm using the fundamental theorem of ring homomorphisms which states $\frac{R}{\text{ker}(\psi)}\approx\text{Im}(\psi)$ where $R$ is a ring, $\psi$ is any ring homomorphism with domain $R$, $\text{ker}(\psi):=\{r\in R:\psi(r)=\mathbf 0\}$ is the kernel of $\psi$, $\text{Im}(\psi)$ is the range of $\psi$ and $\mathbf 0$ is the additive identity of $\text{Im}(\psi)$.